# How to read name of a registry key

Tags: c#, asp.net

something like this :-

```
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key;
key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Office\\15.0\Outlook\\Preferences");
String GetRegistryValue = (String)key.GetValue("MaximumAttachmentSize").ToString();
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you want to achieve exactly? You have already opened a key. So what are you trying to ask?

Answer (score 1):

your question is a little unclear.
if you want to open a key ( as you know):

```
var key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("software\\microsoft\\windows\\currentversion\\");
```

and for getting name of sub keys and opening one of sub keys:

```
 var subKeys = key.GetSubKeyNames();  
 var subKey = key.OpenSubKey(subKeys[0]);
```

and you can get name of values of a key by:

```
var valueNames = subKey.GetValueNames();
```

and use `GetValue` for getting a value from registry.

anything missing?